# Repeat data on pages generated by horizontal subreport in crystal reports

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subreport, crystal-reports-2010

I've got a bit of a problem with a Crystal Report and I'm hoping someone can help me out. I am using crystal reports 13_0_4 with vs2010.

Basically I have a report that looks somewhat like this:

[image]

And i have some issues with the subreport data when it spans more then one pages because i want to repeat the initial data on every page, and i cant seem to be able to make that happen. Keep in mind that the subreport displays data horizontally(I used the Format with Multiple Columns property).

right now the output looks somewhat like this:

[image]

and i want it to look like this:

[image]